# Using the Cloudant-Python Library to connect using API Keys

Tags: python, couchdb, cloudant

I am trying to use the `cloudant` python library (http://cloudant-labs.github.io/cloudant-python/) in a `Flask` application but I can't see where you would use API keys to connect to your cloudant account

I tried this:

```
import cloudant

account = cloudant.Account('account_name')
login = account.login('public_key', 'private_key')
```

But it doesn't do anything

Comment: what error do you get (e.g. when you do assert login.status_code == 200)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you posted this to github.  I wanted others to be able to find the answer.

https://github.com/cloudant-labs/cloudant-python/issues/43:

```
import cloudant

account = cloudant.Account(USERNAME, auth=(API_KEY, API_SECRET))
```

Answer (score 0):

not cloud ant but raw code

```
import requests
import json

#basic authentication
auth = ('account', 'private_key')

post_url = "https://account_name.cloudant.com/database".format(auth[0])
r = requests.put(post_url, auth=auth)

print json.dumps(r.json(), indent=1)
```